# I Assembled hello.asm with NASM But Can't Run hello.o (Mac os x)

Tags: macos, assembly, nasm, file-permissions, chmod

I tried $ chmod -rwx hello.o but it still sais that permission was denied as shown in the picture:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UW9FC.png)

Comment: You can't run object files. You need to link it to an executable file. In your case (OS/X) you'll probably want to use NASM to create a MACHO32 file rather than ELF43 and then iink it with _LD_ or maybe easier _GCC_

Comment: When I said ELF43 I meant ELF32

Comment: Also `-` turns given permissions **off** when used with `chmod`. Why haven't you at least checked the result?

Comment: Sorry, I read it wrong and now came across with a different error. What should I try. The tutorial that I am reading sais to use: ld -m elf_i386 -s -o hello hello.o. But the new error is that: ld: file not found: elf_i386